# Derivative of a set of points

Tags: r, numerical-methods, derivative

So I know you can find the derivative of something like: "x^3-6*x^2" by doing: `D(expression(x^3-6*x^2), 'x')`, but what if I need to find the first derivative maximum of a list of values such as:

`value <- c(610,618,627,632,628,634,634,628,634,642,637,643,653,666,684,717,787,923,1197,1716,2638,4077,5461,7007,8561,9994,11278,12382,13382,14252)`

these values are the y coordinate and the x coordinate starts at 1 and increments by 1. IE the first point is (1,610) second is (2,618) etc. -Thanks

Comment: What about `vec[ which.max(diff(vec)) ]` (where `vec` is your vector of numbers)?

Comment: Are you trying to compute numerical first derivatives over the entire list, then take the maximum?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the package `numDerive` from CRAN. It has a function `grad` that computes derivative of a function at a point. Example:

```
f = function(x) x^3 - 6*x^2
library(numDeriv)
grad(f, 1) #derivative of f at x=1
```

To solve your problem with a list of values, use a for loop:

```
xval <- c(YOUR VALUES HERE)
xval.derivatives <- c() #empty vector to hold
for(i in 1:length(xval)) xval.derivatives[i] <- grad(f,xval[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

The `gradient` function from the pracma package calculates the derivative from a vector of values.

```
library(pracma)

value <- c(610,618,627,632,628,634,634,628,634,642,637,643,653,666,684,717,787,923,1197,1716,2638,4077,5461,7007,8561,9994,11278,12382,13382,14252)
value_prime <- pracma::gradient(value, h1 = 1)
plot(value_prime)
```

[image]

Alternatively, fit a spline.

```
spl <- smooth.spline(1:length(value), y=value)
pred <- predict(spl)
pred.prime <- predict(spl, deriv=1)
plot(pred.prime, type = 'b')
```

[image]

If you are interested in higher derivatives, check the `pspline` package.